# Uncaught type error not a function or iterable in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

Its displaying redux is not a function or iterable in react js. I checked all my code and seen some others iterable functions but there are no answers for my error.https://i.stack.imgur.com/E4IkQ.png

This is my code.

GlobalState.js

```
import React, { createContext, useReduer } from 'react';
import AppReducer from './AppReducer';

const initialState = {
    transactions: [
        { id: 1, text: 'Flower', amount: -20 },
        { id: 2, text: 'Salary', amount: 300 },
        { id: 3, text: 'Book', amount: -10 },
        { id: 4, text: 'Camera', amount: 150 }
    ]
}

export const GlobalContext = createContext(initialState);

export const GlobalProvider = ({ children }) => {
    const [state, dispatch] = useReduer(AppReducer, initialState);

    return (<GlobalContext.Provider value={{
        transactions: state.transactions
    }}>
        {children}
    </GlobalContext.Provider>);
}
```

AppReducer.js

```
/* eslint-disable import/no-anonymous-default-export */
export default (state, action) => {
    switch(action.type) {
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import { Header } from './components/Header';
import { Balance } from './components/Balance';
import { IncomeExpenses } from './components/IncomeExpenses';
import { TransactionList } from './components/TransactionList';
import { AddTransaction } from './components/AddTransaction';
import { GlobalProvider } from './context/GlobalState';

function App() {
  return (
    <GlobalProvider>
      <Header />
      <div className='container'>
          <Balance />
          <IncomeExpenses />
          <TransactionList />
          <AddTransaction />
      </div>
    </GlobalProvider>
      
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: From your code, I see you have typed `useReduer`, not `useReducer`. Could you fix it and try again? If it's still breaking, please edit the post

Answer (score 0):

I see the post is still open after a few days, so I'm posting my comment as an answer to close it.

> From your code, I see you have typed `useReduer`, not `useReducer`. Could you fix it and try again? If it's still breaking, please edit the post